# Unable to make basic socket.io emit work with Swift

Tags: ios, node.js, swift, socket.io

I've looked at a couple demos that overlapped quite a bit but I'm not able to get a basic emit to work.  I get a connection message with the server file but nothing on an attempt to emit from the client.  Here's what I have in each file:

SocketIOManager.swift

```
import UIKit

class SocketIOManager: NSObject {

    static let sharedInstance = SocketIOManager()

    override init() {
        super.init()
    }

    var socket: SocketIOClient = SocketIOClient(socketURL: NSURL(string: "myURL")! as URL)

    func establishConnection() {
        socket.connect()
    }


    func closeConnection() {
        socket.disconnect()
    }

    func testSocket() {
        socket.emit("test")
    }

}
```

AppDelegate.swift

```
func applicationDidEnterBackground(_ application: UIApplication) {
   SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.closeConnection()
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {
   SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.establishConnection()

}
```

ViewController

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()      
        SocketIOManager.sharedInstance.testSocket()
    }
```

index.js server file

```
io.on('connection', function(clientSocket){
  console.log('a user connected');


  clientSocket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
    });

  clientSocket.on("test", function(){
    console.log('test')
  });

});
```

So again, while I'm getting the print statements for connection and disconnection, I'm getting nothing for a regular emit function.

Comment: where is the emmit on server side?

Comment: The emit I'm trying to make work is coming from the client.  It's inside the testSocket() function.

Comment: so it's not logging test on console correct

Comment: Correct, the on.connection message prints but not the test message.

Comment: please check below answer. Index.js was having errors

Answer (score 0):

Please try to update your index.js

by this

```
io.on('connection', function(clientSocket){
  console.log('a user connected');


  clientSocket.on('disconnect', function(){
    console.log('user disconnected');
    });

  clientSocket.on("test", function(){
    console.log('test');
  });

});
```

as there is missing `)` at the end of `disconnect`.

Comment: That was just a mistake on my part - I was cutting out unrelated code that didn't need to be included in the question and accidentally cut that off.  I get no errors when running index.js so all my brackets and parentheses are matching.  I also get the disconnect console message when disconnecting.

Comment: can you post snap of index of js

Comment: and can you also try calling test method on the click of button?

Comment: ^^ I had tried that previously and it didn't work, but when I tried again, it did work.  It must be some kind of timing issue, like that the socket needs time to connect to the server before emits are functional.  Thanks!  Now on to client listeners...